# looping through session variables in joomla 2.5?

Tags: arrays, session, joomla2.5

I have a multi dimensional session array 'cart' . I am stuck with the looping through this array .
How can i loop through this array . when i used

```
foreach($session->get('cart') as $key=>$val) {

}
```

it shows error. Is there any method ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach($_SESSION as $cart => $val) {
echo  'Cart ' . $cart . ' is: ' . $val . '<br />';
}
```